# odoo context.get.active_id is not working

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, odoo-8, odoo

I have create a Registration module in my School Management System in ODOO 8.
In that module I have a one2many field called enrollment_ids. I want to get activated registration_id when create new enrollment. but it's not working.

Here is my code.

```
def default_get(self, cr, uid, fields, context=None):
    data = super(op_enrollment, self).default_get(cr, uid, fields, context=context)
    registration_id = context.get('active_id', False)
    return True
```

Why can't I get the active registration_id. It always return False.

Answer (score 3):

Try it this way, write this on your XML code:

```
<field name="enrollment_ids" widget="one2many_list" context="{'default_registration_id': active_id}">
   <tree>
      ...
   </tree>
</field>
```

Comment: It's sad that it doesn't work right after creating the record. I mean, `active_id` is not set until you save the record.